# How to search crashes on google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics, crash-reports

Is there an API I can use to search for a specific crash on Google play console?

Whenever I go into the console on the web UI, there is only the ability to filter for crashes. However, this isn't very useful for finding a specific crash (for example, native crashes are desymbolicated much better on google play store than crashlytics, so I'd rather look for the crash on play store if possible).

Comment: You can integrate the crashlatic OR Firbase crash aynaltics